# Is it possible to instruct msbuild to output its execution plan without actually building the code?

Tags: msbuild

Suppose we have sequential build, i.e. a single node. msbuild parses the solution file, examines all the project dependencies and decides to build the projects in a certain order.

Is it possible to instruct msbuild just to output this order without actually building anything?

P.S.

I realize I can implement this logic myself using MSBuild API. I can read the solution file and all the projects and build the dependency graph myself. I am specifically curious if msbuild can do it, since it does this logic anyway already.

Comment: I've been working with MSBuild for quite some time but I never encountered such a feature :(

Answer (score 0):

There are various diagnostic features in MSBuild but currently there isn't a feature that is like reporting a SQL execution plan or like PowerShell's [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3#-whatif) parameter.

You could submit a feature request at [dotnet/msbuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild).

If you do submit a feature request, provide the link here.